# Downloading large data sets on overpass-turbo?

Tags: overpass-api

I'm trying to download historical data from overpass-turbo and I keep getting this error.

```
Error: runtime error: open64: 0 Success /osm3s_v0.7.54_osm_base Dispatcher_Client::request_read_and_idx::timeout. The server is probably too busy to handle your request.
```

This is after trying to increase the timeout and maxsize on the query and using the "raw data directly from Overpass API" export function. I need to do this for all of US and Canada.  Breaking it up by state and province is fine or one big download will work as well.  Am I exceeding the limits and need to find another way of doing this?  The files don't seem to be too big.  California is about 10MB and Ohio is about 2MB.  Here are my basic queries.

```
 [adiff:"2016-10-23T15:00:00Z","2017-10-22T15:00:00Z"];

{{geocodeArea:california}}->.searchArea;
(
  way["highway"="motorway_link"](area.searchArea);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;



[adiff:"2016-10-23T15:00:00Z","2017-10-22T15:00:00Z"][timeout:99999][maxsize:10737418240];

{{geocodeArea:california}}->.searchArea;
(
  way["highway"="motorway_link"](area.searchArea);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Comment: for large downloads use http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america.html

Comment: This is intentional, because the server would be overloaded most of the time otherwise. You can set up your own overpass instance on a full or part planet database if you need the query part.

Comment: Besides, both timeout and maxsize values are both ridiculously large: 99999 seconds is more than 1 day (!), maxsize is >10GB. That's why the query always runs into a timeout. As @AndreJ already said, running your own instance is way to go.

Comment: @Mapperz I need the historical data and the geofabrik downloads don't work for me.  I'm on a PC and unless you know how to get osmosis to work on one that is out of the question.

Comment: @mmd, that's just a sample. I tried a bunch of different combos for time and size. I got it to work once with out both and the file was 10MB which doesn't seem like a lot.

Comment: @AndreJ, I need the query.  Because I need historical data this seems to be the only way to get it.  The 'duplicate' question doesn't answer mine nor does it explain any file size limits.  I can't get osmosis to work on a pc.  Is there documentation on how to set up your own instance?

Comment: @brink: 10MB result size is not important in terms of how much resources your queries consume on the server. You need to take into account that you're analyzing all changes across a whole year is a fairly large area. And of course the server has some rate limiting in place which would delay or even block repeated attempts to run large queries.

Comment: @mmd, Ok, that makes sense.  I really only need a snapshot of the database one year ago to analyze changes but that seems to be unattainable on a PC with out paying for it.

Comment: You may ask at help.openstreetmap.org for a more detailed answer from the OSM dev people. BTW osmosis works for me on a Windows PC, but I have not tried it on a full planet history file. You may use a virtual box with Ubuntu inside to workaround Windows-OS related limitations.

Comment: @AndreJ, sorry I meant osmium.  I can't get it to work on Windows 7 so  I may go the virtual machine route.  Can you pull historical osm data using osmosis?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Apart from that, http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america.osh.pbf might be suitable for your needs, much smaller than the full history planet. For the virtual machine, take Ubuntu zesty to get an up-to-date osmium version. If successful, think of self-answering your question.

Comment: BTW: related osmium-tool issue: https://github.com/osmcode/osmium-tool/issues/59

Comment: try some other instances https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API#Public_Overpass_API_instances

Answer (score 0):

> Am I exceeding the limits

Given that quoted error includes

> Dispatcher_Client::request_read_and_idx::timeout. The server is probably too busy to handle your request.

Yes, you requested more than server is able to provide. Try splitting queries into smaller.

Also, from comments:

> Besides, both timeout and maxsize values are both ridiculously large: 99999 seconds is more than 1 day (!), maxsize is >10GB

It is possible that server rejects queries with outrageous maxsize and timeout values.